# Initializing an empty array in Julia with a large number of arrays inside

Tags: arrays, initialization, julia

I'm trying to initialize an empty array in Julia 1.1 with 6 elements, where the `i`-th element consists of 1000 Arrays, which will be filled with a loop. For example, if the `i`-th element contains 3 Arrays, I can do `fill([Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1} ,Array{Float64,1}],6,1)`. But how can I obtain the empty 1000 Arrays without copying `Array{Float64,1}` 1000 times?

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. If your array is empty it cannot contain 6 elements. Also, do you want an array of arrays, or an array of arrays of arrays? Finally, the `Array{Float64}`s are not arrays, they are type variables.

Comment: Oh, and also, are you trying to *initialize* or *pre-allocate*?

Comment: I want to create an empty object to fill with values with a for loop. I have an array of 6 values to which I will apply a function 1000 times. The function returns an array of type {Float64,1} . So, my empty array will be the place where I want to store the 1000 arrays that are returned by the function , for the 6 values that I have ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples depending on what you want actually to do:

Set of empty arrays:

```
julia> [[Float64[] for a in 1:3] for b in 1:6]
6-element Array{Array{Array{Float64,1},1},1}:
 [[], [], []]
 [[], [], []]
 [[], [], []]
 [[], [], []]
 [[], [], []]
 [[], [], []]
```

An uninitialized three dimensional Array having size `6x3x2` (perhaps having a 3D array is actually more convenient than Array of Arrays of Arrays - depends on your use case):

```
julia> Array{Float64,3}(undef, 6, 3, 2)
6×3×2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 9.00033e-316  1.52477e-315  1.52473e-315
 7.95655e-316  1.52477e-315  1.52473e-315
 1.52474e-315  8.18796e-316  1.52477e-315
 7.95655e-316  1.52477e-315  1.52474e-315
 1.52474e-315  1.52473e-315  1.52474e-315
 8.03142e-316  1.52473e-315  1.52477e-315

[:, :, 2] =
 7.97808e-316  1.52473e-315  0.0
 8.07774e-316  1.52474e-315  0.0
 1.52474e-315  1.52473e-315  0.0
 1.52474e-315  1.52473e-315  0.0
 7.96305e-316  0.0           0.0
 1.52473e-315  0.0           0.0
```

Allocated set of uninitialized Arrays:

```
julia> [[Vector{Float64}(undef,2) for a in 1:3] for b in 1:6]
6-element Array{Array{Array{Float64,1},1},1}:
 [[1.60704e-315, 1.60693e-315], [5.93041e-316, 1.69135e-315], [1.69002e-315, 1.69135e-315]]
 [[5.93223e-316, 5.93223e-316], [5.92882e-316, 4.94066e-324], [5.93223e-316, 5.93223e-316]]
 [[5.92884e-316, 2.122e-314], [5.92883e-316, 1.60853e-315], [5.93041e-316, 5.92887e-316]]
 [[1.69002e-315, 5.92885e-316], [1.60705e-315, 1.60693e-315], [5.93041e-316, 1.69136e-315]]
 [[1.69002e-315, 1.69136e-315], [5.93223e-316, 5.93223e-316], [5.92882e-316, 5.93043e-316]]
 [[5.93223e-316, 5.93223e-316], [5.92884e-316, 5.93043e-316], [5.92883e-316, 5.93223e-316]]
```

Comment: Oh nice ! Very useful ways of creating what I want :-)

Comment: There is a big problem with this answer: aliasing. In both the first and third example you are filling the structure with references to the same array. Try `A = fill(fill(Float64[],3),6,1)` and then `push!(A[1][1], 1234)`. All of the arrays are the same.

Comment: @DNF, yes you are right - I should have used the comprehension instead. I edited the answer to be correct, thanks for pointing that out.